# Run NSOperation on Main Thread

Tags: multithreading, nsoperation

I built a NSOperation to run on a background thread, but I have since optimized the operation such that I might be better suited running it in the main thread.  Is there a way to direct my NSOperation to run on the main thread instead of a background thread so that I can test things out without significant refactoring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in the `NSOperationQueue` by using `mainQueue`

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: So instead of adding the operation to my own queue, get a reference to the mainQueue and it to that.  That sounds good.  The other approach I was considering was not running the operation on a queue at all, and just issuing a [myOperation start] call.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please note that "[cancelAllOperations doesn't work for \[NSOperationQueue mainQueue\]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590670/cancelalloperations-doesnt-work-for-nsoperationqueue-mainqueue).