# cancelAllOperations doesn't work for [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

`cancelAllOperations()` doesn't work on the mainQueue (the `cancel()` method is not called on the `NSOperation` object). Am I missing something?
I have to iterate through all operations and call the `cancel()` method to get it work.

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen `-cancelAllOperations` work just fine. Maybe you need to provide more context.

Comment: failing for me in just the way described, today

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you say that you're using the `mainQueue` for `NSURLConnection`. You probably want to use a custom queue for `NSURLConnection`-based operations, not `mainQueue`, anyway (you can use `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to enjoy concurrency while controlling the degree of concurrency). If using delegate-based `NSURLConnection`, you can still schedule the connection on the main queue (or create your own `NSThread` with its own runloop, like AFNetworking does). But you probably want to use custom queue for the operations, themselves.

Answer (score 6):

I can also confirm that cancelAllOperations does not work on [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] (at least on my iOS 5.0 Simulator). Might be intentionally designed like that since it is a shared instance.

My simple workaround is just to subclass NSOperation or NSBlockOperation without overriding anything and then do something like this:

```
-(void)cancelMyOperationsInMainQueue {    
    for (NSOperation* o in [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] operations]) {
        if ([o isKindOfClass:[MyOperation class]]) {
            [o cancel];
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah can also confirm it doesn't call cancel method on the operations, it just sets `isCancelled = YES`

My solution: `[[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] operations] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(cancel)];`